# Merge array items by category

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have this array:

```
[ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ]
```

and I want to merge the content so that I will have:

```
[ [ 'TWENTY', 60 ],
  [ 'TEN', 20 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 15 ],
  [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.50 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.2 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.04 ]]
```

I tried iterating through the array and summing values but had no success. 
Really appreciate your help.
Mattia P

Comment: Why are you saving the data as array(s)? Working with object literals would make the job much easier (to work with and to read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) you can group by the first element of the inner array.

Try as the following:

```js
const array = [ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ];
  
const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(f => f[0] === c[0]);
  
  if (found) found[1] += c[1];
  else a.push(c);

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in one loop with an object as a map:

```js
const array = [ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ];
  
const result = array.reduce((map,[key,val]) => {
  map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + val;
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(Object.entries(result));
```

`Object.entries(result)` turns it from a nice object that you can access like `result.PENNY` back into the array format you want. You may find it easier to use as the map, in which case simply omit the `Object.entries(...)`.

Comment: beat me to the same answer. Nice use of lazy evaluations and destructuring!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single line approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var data = [['TWENTY', 20], ['TWENTY', 20], ['TWENTY', 20], ['TEN', 10], ['TEN', 10], ['FIVE', 5], ['FIVE', 5], ['FIVE', 5], ['DOLLAR', 1], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['DIME', 0.1], ['DIME', 0.1], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01]],
    result = Array.from(data.reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + v), new Map));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you see any particular advantage here in a `Map` over a plain object (as used in Klaycon's answer and mine?)  Perhaps its slightly more correct semantically, but I see little difference.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it was just for completeness. i still ahve no idea which approach is better or faster or more correct in any dimension.

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [['TWENTY', 20],
 ['TWENTY', 20],
 ['TWENTY', 20],
 ['TEN', 10],
 ['TEN', 10],
 ['FIVE', 5],
 ['FIVE', 5],
 ['FIVE', 5],
 ['DOLLAR', 1],
 ['QUARTER', 0.25],
 ['QUARTER', 0.25],
 ['DIME', 0.1],
 ['DIME', 0.1],
 ['PENNY', 0.01],
 ['PENNY', 0.01],
 ['PENNY', 0.01],
 ['PENNY', 0.01]];

 const b = {};
 const c = [];

 for (const [name, value] of a) {
  if (!b[name]) {
    b[name] = 0;
  }
  b[name] = b[name] + value
 }
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(b)) {
  c.push([key, value])
 }

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `reduce` and `findIndex`.

```js
const data = [[ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TEN', 10 ], [ 'TEN', 10 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'DIME', 0.1 ], [ 'DIME', 0.1 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ]];

const res = data.reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
 let index = a.findIndex(x => x[0] === k);
 
 if (index === -1) {
  a.push([k, v]);
 } else {
  a[index][1] += v;
 }
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Compare the code from Klaycon, though.  (Or my similar answer.)  There is room for simplification here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only with one iteration:

```
const array = [ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
[ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
[ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
[ 'TEN', 10 ],
[ 'TEN', 10 ],
[ 'FIVE', 5 ],
[ 'FIVE', 5 ],
[ 'FIVE', 5 ],
[ 'DOLLAR', 1 ],
[ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
[ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ],
[ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
[ 'DIME', 0.1 ],
[ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
[ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
[ 'PENNY', 0.01 ],
[ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ];

let result = {};
array.forEach(item => {
      if(result[item[0]]) {
         result[item[0]][1] +=item[1]
      } else {
         result[item[0]] = item;   
      }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abstract this to a simple function, it might look like this:

```js
const total = array => Object .entries (array .reduce (
  (acc, [name, val]) => ({...acc, [name]: (acc [name] || 0) + val})
  , {}
))

const array = [ [ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TWENTY', 20 ], [ 'TEN', 10 ], [ 'TEN', 10 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'FIVE', 5 ], [ 'DOLLAR', 1 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'DIME', 0.1 ], [ 'DIME', 0.1 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ], [ 'PENNY', 0.01 ] ];

console .log (total (array))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```